# Marking all occurrences of substring in string

Tags: c

How would one achieve marking all occurrences of a substring in a string?

This is the code I got so far.

```
char *tmp = line;
int count = 0;
while ((tmp = strstr2(tmp, argv[2])) != NULL) {
    int start = (int) (tmp - line);
    count += start;
    printf("%.*s", count, line);
    printf(">" %.*s" "<", strlen2(argv[2]), line + start);
}
printf("\n");
```

For example, in string **"hehe xd hehe xd"**, if I was searching for **"xd"** I want the output to look like **"hehe >xd< hehe >xd<"**

Obviously does not work, but I am stuck on this and can not come up with another solution.

I can only use facilities from the `<stdio.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` headers.

Comment: are you allowed to use STL ? can you use c++ to solve this ?

Comment: Does `"aba"` in `"ababa"` count as 1 or 2 occurrences?

Comment: What does `strstr2()` do?  How is it different from `strstr()`?  A quick search via Google doesn't reveal anything enlightening, so I'm not sure how we're supposed to know/guess.

Comment: strstr2 is normal strstr, i for whatever reasons cant use normal strstr. i would mark the whole "ababa" thing.

Comment: i can only use <stdio.h> and <stdlib.h> libraries

Comment: @J.Hoe Required like " can only use <stdio.h> and <stdlib.h> libraries" belong in the post.  Recommend  appending that.  Easy to miss comments.